# How to retrieve value from SQLite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from my DB but I have some problem.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *action=[[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *queryStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ACTIONNAME FROM ACTIONS WHERE ACTIONSYMBOL = '%@'", symbol];

// Prepare the query for execution
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Create a new address from the found row
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        action = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]; // fails on this line
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return action;
}
```

(the parameter symbol come from outside)

When I run this, it fails at the line with the call to `stringWithUTF8String` with `sqlite3_column_text` results.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use FMDatabase framework - it's a great wrapper for sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `sqlite3_column_text`, you're using the index `1`, but it takes a zero-based index. Use `0` instead of `1`. See the [SQLite `sqlite_column_XXX` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), which says:

> The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.

---

By the way, since `stringWithUTF8String` throws an exception if you pass it a `NULL` value, it's often safer to check the result if `sqlite3_column_text` is not `NULL` before proceeding, and handle the error gracefully otherwise. Also, you might want to check for `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_prepare_v2` errors, like so:

```
NSString *queryStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ACTIONNAME FROM ACTIONS WHERE ACTIONSYMBOL = '%@'", symbol];  // note, it can be dangerous to use `stringWithFormat` to build SQL; better to use `?` placeholders in your SQL and then use `sqlite3_bind_text` to bind the `symbol` value with the `?` placeholder

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int rc;
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const unsigned char *value = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);  // use zero

        if (value) {
            NSString *action = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)value];

            // now do whatever you want with `action`, e.g. add it to an array or what
        } else {
            // handle the error (or NULL value) gracefully here
        }

        // make sure to check for errors in `sqlite3_step`

        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

---

Incidentally, as the above illustrates, to correctly perform all of the error checking is a little cumbersome. This is where [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) can be useful, simplifying the above to (where `db` is an `FMDatabase` object that has been opened):

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT ACTIONNAME FROM ACTIONS WHERE ACTIONSYMBOL = ?", symbol];
if (!rs) {
    NSLog(@"%s: executeQuery failed: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);
    return;
}

while ([rs next]) {
    NSString *action = [rs stringForColumnIndex:0];

    // do whatever you want with `action` here
}

[rs close];
```

And if you use `?` placeholders (rather than using `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL, which is dangerous) the benefits of using FMDB are even more compelling.

Comment: This is old but it's far safer to bind values into a query with `sqlite3_bind_xxx` instead of building the query using `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: Agreed! That was the whole point of the latter example (with the `?` in the SQL statement, and `executeQuery` does the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for you!). Always use the `?` placeholder and bind values (whether with something like FMDB that does it for you, or manually with `sqlite3_bind_xxx`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/1271826 if doing it manually.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even notice the last code example. I got focused on the initial code while I was scanning search results looking for a duplicate for another question.

Comment: No worries. It was a good observation. One should always avoid string interpolation for values supplied to a `where` clause. I only did it in my first example because that’s how the OP did it and I was narrowly helping the OP address the immediate problem (the index into the results), but you’re right, that one should always use `?` placeholders in the `where` clause and bind values.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to collect the results in an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *action = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
     [action addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
}

...
```

You can then see what was collected later:

```
for (NSString *s in action) {
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

**EDIT** As pointed out in @Rob's answer, the first column is `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Why do you think that he will get multiply values? I think, u r wrong.

Comment: @user3245831 So why the `while` loop then?

Comment: @etolstoy Because of the `while` loop and the lack of information about the database schema.

Comment: maybe i don't need the while loop... but its doesn't matter its fail at the row after