# Importing a table of data locally in Ios with Swift and using it for a search function

Tags: ios, database, xcode, swift, core-data

Maybe some of you, can help me with this. I'm new to Iphone app development, my knowledge of programming is mainly javascript and PHP. I want to make an app with a search function that searches in a localy stored table of data with multiple rows. Can you please tell me the best way to do this. I've looked at tutorials about Coredata, but all the tutorials are about inputing, saving and getting the data and nothing about importing and managing data in ios. I'm taking about examples in Swift.

Comment: Have you considered using an sqlite database? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift

Comment: Yes, but I havn't figured out how to do it in Swift and I way to far to do any coding in C.

Comment: If you know PHP I assume you have worked with `sql` databases before? the difficult bit with iOS is just getting the database setup in the first place, after that running queries is a breeze. I use a swift wrapper for the database part - https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB

Comment: How do I import the data. Should I upload a sql file. Where do i insert an manage the data? Is there som kind of admin for the database like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Checkout the readme of the `SQLiteDB` wrapper it explains how to add the database to your project and what to name it.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks SQLiteDB did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you're going to use the CRUD operation on the database(CoreData) to achieve what you've said above. So if you're good enough with the basics of coredata you can achieve this using the typical examples available in any tutorial for CRUD operations. By the way still you're looking for a piece of code demonstration you can refer this [link](https://github.com/SureshKumarD/SearchBarWithCoreData)