# creating Instance for sqlite3 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm working in a Swift project and using sqlite database in it. In Objective-C, we just import `sqlite3.h` in class file and create a instance for `sqlite3` like 
 
`sqlite3 *db;` 
and we use it through out the program. 
Like wise how do I achieve it in swift ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing an SQLite Database in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift)

Comment: In that link they haven't mentioned how to create a instance for sqlite3.

Comment: Yes they have, chapter 2 of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/2227743. You could use the excellent https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift instead, anyway.

Comment: Follow this step by step : http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/use-sqlite-database-swift/

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData/blob/master/SwiftData.swift

```
private class SQLiteDB {

    class var sharedInstance: SQLiteDB {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SQLiteDB()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    var sqliteDB: COpaquePointer = nil
    var dbPath = SQLiteDB.createPath()
    var inTransaction = false
    var isConnected = false
    var openWithFlags = false
    var savepointsOpen = 0
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("SwiftData.DatabaseQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)


    // MARK: - Database Handling Functions

    //open a connection to the sqlite3 database
    func open() -> Int? {

        if inTransaction || openWithFlags || savepointsOpen > 0 {
            return nil
        }
        if sqliteDB != nil || isConnected {
            return nil
        }
        let status = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &sqliteDB)
        if status != SQLITE_OK {
            println("SwiftData Error -> During: Opening Database")
            println("                -> Code: \(status) - " + SDError.errorMessageFromCode(Int(status)))
            if let errMsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.sqliteDB)) {
                println("                -> Details: \(errMsg)")
            }
            return Int(status)
        }
        isConnected = true
        return nil

    }
}
```

Don't forget to link your target against **libsqlite3.dylib**