# How to import sqlite3.h in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, xcode8-beta2

I'm new to databases, and have seen a few solutions, but the answers are usually too technical for me to understand. I've read about adding SQL to the source files, and about Bridges, etc. I have yet to come across a good step by step procedure. I'm following a tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73XRidPrLwY&feature=youtu.be )but it's outdated. When I add the line

```
import sqlite3.h
```

I get the error

```
No such module 'sqlite3.h'
```

Not sure what to do from there. I read about creating a new file > new > file > Cocoa Touch Class > Name it 'Temporary'... but I don't know which subclass to use. Thank you for any help here.

Comment: There are bunch of good tutorial about db in iOS. Check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift, but if there isn't any specific reason, `CoreData` is also a good option to consider. This is simply a wrapper of sql but easy to reuse. https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: See step 1 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift/28642293#28642293.