# Should I use Core Data or SQLite to have better App Size

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I have a requirement to keep the app size under 3MB. There will be small amount of offline data storage in the app. I would like to know if I should use **SQLite *or* Core Data** (Which I personally prefer) to have better app size.

I will be coding the app in SWIFT3. I found out that we would require to use a wrapper to use SQLite anyway, which is basically what Core Data offers.

P.S.: I would personally like to stick to SWIFT3 rather than switching to objectiveC. Any additional tips for better app size and, opinions on if I should switch to objectiveC would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the app package download size or the size of the app when it one the phone?

Comment: 1) Core Data is more than "basically a wrapper to use SQLite".  2) You *can* use SQLite directly from Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/1187415.

Comment: Maintaining the code would be easy and handy if you'll use Core Data.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that it could make a difference at all to the bundle download size.  There is no SQL file created yet when the app is downloaded.  The main issues with app download sizes are resources - like images and sounds.

Comment: What did you measure when you tried it for your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the usual **"it depends"**.

If you are using it to store a minimal amount of data, like in this case, it really does not matter, but for ease of use and the easy methods of dealing with objects, I think that Core Data is a better choice. Nonetheless, it has its downsides (don't even get me started on thread concurrencies), but it's a useful extension for storing, especially if you are dealing with objects.

Comment: I am satisfied with this answer. After a LONG discussion with client and their technical team. We decided to use Core Data and SWIFT3 with an additional buffer space for 1.5MB, "just in case". Thanks :)