# Swift SQLite3 syntax and bind

Tags: swift, date, sqlite

first of all, these are my functions:

1. Insert function

   ```
   func insert(book : Book) throws -> Bool {
       var insertPointer: OpaquePointer? = nil
       let query = "INSERT INTO BOOK (bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

       defer{
           sqlite3_finalize(insertPointer)
       }

       if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &insertPointer, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
           sqlite3_bind_text(insertPointer, 1, book.bookTitle, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(insertPointer, 2, book.bookAuthor, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(insertPointer, 3, book.bookDesc, -1, nil)
         //sqlite3_bind_date(insertPointer, 4, book.bookDate,nil)
         //sqlite3_bind_image(insertPointer, 5, book.bookImg, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(insertPointer, 6, book.createdBy, -1, nil)

           guard sqlite3_step(insertPointer) == SQLITE_DONE else {
               throw SQLiteError.Step(message: errorMessage)
           }
       } else {
           throw SQLiteError.Prepare(message: errorMessage)
       }

       return true
   }
   ```
2. Update function

   ```
   func update(book : Book) throws -> Bool {
       var updatePointer: OpaquePointer? = nil
       var query = "UPDATE Book SET bookName = ?, bookAuthor = ?, bookDesc = ?, bookDate = ?, bookImg = ?, createdBy = ?, WHERE bookId = ?"

       defer{
           sqlite3_finalize(updatePointer)
       }

       if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &updatePointer, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

           sqlite3_bind_text(updatePointer, 2, book.bookAuthor, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(updatePointer, 3, book.bookDesc, -1, nil)
           //sqlite3_bind_date(updatePointer, 4, book.bookDate,nil)
           //sqlite3_bind_image(updatePointer, 5, book.bookImg, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(updatePointer, 6, book.createdBy, -1, nil)
           sqlite3_bind_text(updatePointer, 7, book.bookId, -1, nil)
           guard sqlite3_step(updatePointer) == SQLITE_DONE else {
               throw SQLiteError.Step(message: errorMessage)
           }
       } else {
           throw SQLiteError.Prepare(message: errorMessage)
       }

       return true
   }
   ```
3. Delete function

   ```
   func delete(book : Book) throws -> Bool {
       var deletePointer: OpaquePointer? = nil
       var query = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE bookId = ?"

       defer{
           sqlite3_finalize(deletePointer)
       }

       if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &deletePointer, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
           sqlite3_bind_text(updatePointer, 1, book.bookId, -1, nil)
           guard sqlite3_step(deletePointer) == SQLITE_DONE else {
               throw SQLiteError.Step(message: errorMessage)
           }
       } else {
           throw SQLiteError.Prepare(message: errorMessage)
       }

       return true
   }
   ```

And I have a `Book` class like this:

```
class Book{
    var bookId : Int
    var bookImg : Data
    var bookTitle : String
    var bookAuthor : String
    var bookDesc : String
    var bookDate : Date
    var createdBy : String

    init(bookId : Int, bookImg : Data, bookTitle : String, bookAuthor : String, bookDesc : String, bookDate : Date, createdBy : String){
        self.bookId = bookId
        self.bookImg = bookImg
        self.bookTitle = bookTitle
        self.bookAuthor = bookAuthor
        self.bookDesc = bookDesc
        self.bookDate = bookDate
        self.createdBy = createdBy
    }
}
```

I am new to Swift and SQLite. My question is that:

1. Am I doing it right with the parameter binding?
2. How do I bind `Data` and `Date` type into SQLite query? (the commented line in code above)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does the `SQLiteError` type come from? Where is `errorMessage` defined?

Comment: SQLiteError is enum defined in the same file. errorMessage is defined along with the functions in the class (not Book class).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You asked:

> 1. Am I doing it right with the parameter binding?

Largely.

- When binding strings, it's probably prudent to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` as the last parameter to `sqlite3_bind_text` and `sqlite3_bind_blob`, as defined here:

  ```
  internal let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
  internal let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
  ```
- When binding `bookId`, you want to use `sqlite3_bind_int64`.
- In `delete` you're referring to `updatePointer`. Change that to `deletePointer`.
- You should probably be checking these `sqlite3_bind_xxx` return codes and throwing an error if they're not `SQLITE_OK`, too.

You then asked:

> 2. How do I bind Data and Date type into SQLite query? (the commented line in code above)

Re date type, SQLite doesn't have a native date type (see http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). So you can either:

- Use `ISODateFormatter` to build a string, and bind the string; if you need fractional seconds, you can use [`withFractionalSeconds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/options/2923300-withfractionalseconds) option (introduced in iOS 11, macOS 10.13, etc.), e.g.:

  ```
  let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
  ```
- If you need milliseconds and need to support those older OS versions, use `DateFormatter` with `dateFormat` of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, a `locale` of `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`, and a `timeZone` of `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`, and again store and retrieve the date as a string and convert it; or
- Use `timeIntervalSince1970` of the `Date`, and insert that as `sqlite3_bind_double`.

The former string alternatives are easiest to use and makes it easy when visually inspecting the database in third party tools. The `timeIntervalSince1970` is arguably a tad more efficient, but it just means you need to use `unixepoch` to convert the double to an intelligible date if looking at the column in third party SQLite tools, which can be a little cumbersome. It's a trade-off of efficiency vs usability.

Re the `Data`, insert that using `sqlite3_bind_blob`.

---

A couple of final minor observations:

- You are deferring the `sqlite3_finalize` before you `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. You should `defer` it *after* `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. You should only be finalizing if prepare succeeded, not if it failed.
- On updates with a `WHERE` clause, you might want to check `sqlite3_changes` to see whether any records changed. For updates by identifier, I changed the functions to throw errors if nothing was updated/deleted.
- Several of these functions were defined as throwing errors as well as returning a boolean. For the update/delete functions that doesn't make sense (because we use the error to know whether it succeeded or not, making the boolean return value redundant). So I removed the `Bool` return type. For other functions (e.g. the `SELECT` routines) a return value obviously does make sense, but not for these pass/fail update routines.
- For the `Book` properties, I removed the `book` prefix. It makes sense to have that prefix in SQL (it makes join queries easier to write), but it's redundant in a Swift type. You generally only use that sort of prefix where it's needed for disambiguation (e.g. `bookDescription`, to avoid confusion with the `CustomStringConvertible` property, `description`).

---

Anyways, pulling that together, you get something like:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let _formatter = DateFormatter()
    _formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
    _formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    _formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    return _formatter
}()

var errorMessage: String { return String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)) }

func insert(_ book: inout Book) throws {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let query = "INSERT INTO book (bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.prepare(message: errorMessage)
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, book.title, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, book.author, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, book.bookDescription, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, dateFormatter.string(from: book.createDate), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard book.image.withUnsafeBytes({ bufferPointer -> Int32 in
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 5, bufferPointer.baseAddress, Int32(book.image.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    }) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, book.createdBy, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE else {
        throw SQLiteError.step(message: errorMessage)
    }

    book.id = Int(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db))
}

func update(_ book: Book) throws {
    guard let id = book.id.flatMap({ Int64($0) }) else {
        throw SQLiteError.noDataChanged
    }

    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let query = "UPDATE Book SET bookName = ?, bookAuthor = ?, bookDesc = ?, bookDate = ?, bookImg = ?, createdBy = ? WHERE bookId = ?"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.prepare(message: errorMessage)
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, book.title, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, book.author, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, book.bookDescription, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, dateFormatter.string(from: book.createDate), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard book.image.withUnsafeBytes({ bufferPointer -> Int32 in
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 5, bufferPointer.baseAddress, Int32(book.image.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    }) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, book.createdBy, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 7, id) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE else {
        throw SQLiteError.step(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_changes(db) > 0 else {
        throw SQLiteError.noDataChanged
    }
}

func delete(_ book: Book) throws {
    guard let id = book.id.flatMap({ Int64($0) }) else {
        throw SQLiteError.noDataChanged
    }

    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let query = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE bookId = ?"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.prepare(message: errorMessage)
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    guard sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, id) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE else {
        throw SQLiteError.step(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_changes(db) > 0 else {
        throw SQLiteError.noDataChanged
    }
}

func select(bookId: Int) throws -> Book {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let query = "SELECT bookId, bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy FROM Book WHERE bookId = ?"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.prepare(message: errorMessage)
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    guard sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, Int64(bookId)) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.bind(message: errorMessage)
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW else {
        throw SQLiteError.step(message: errorMessage)
    }

    return try book(for: statement)
}

func selectAll() throws -> [Book] {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let query = "SELECT bookId, bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy FROM Book"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw SQLiteError.prepare(message: errorMessage)
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    var books = [Book]()

    var rc: Int32
    repeat {
        rc = sqlite3_step(statement)
        guard rc == SQLITE_ROW else { break }
        books.append(try book(for: statement))
    } while rc == SQLITE_ROW

    guard rc == SQLITE_DONE else {
        throw SQLiteError.step(message: errorMessage)
    }

    return books
}

func book(for statement: OpaquePointer?) throws -> Book {
    let bookId = Int(sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0))

    guard let bookNameCString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    let bookName = String(cString: bookNameCString)

    guard let bookAuthorCString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    let bookAuthor = String(cString: bookAuthorCString)

    guard let bookDescCString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    let bookDesc = String(cString: bookDescCString)

    guard let bookDateCString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    guard let bookDate = dateFormatter.date(from: String(cString: bookDateCString)) else {
        throw SQLiteError.invalidDate
    }

    let bookImgCount = Int(sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 5))
    guard bookImgCount > 0 else {
        throw SQLiteError.missingData
    }
    guard let bookImgBlog = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 5) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    let bookImg = Data(bytes: bookImgBlog, count: bookImgCount)

    guard let createdByCString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6) else {
        throw SQLiteError.column(message: errorMessage)
    }
    let createdBy = String(cString: createdByCString)

    return Book(id: bookId, image: bookImg, title: bookName, author: bookAuthor, bookDescription: bookDesc, createDate: bookDate, createdBy: createdBy)
}
```

With these definitions:

```
struct Book {
    var id: Int?
    var image: Data
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var bookDescription: String  // this is the only one where I kept the `book` prefix, simply because `description` is a reserved name
    var createDate: Date
    var createdBy: String
}

enum SQLiteError: Error {
    case open(result: Int32)
    case exec(message: String)
    case prepare(message: String)
    case bind(message: String)
    case step(message: String)
    case column(message: String)
    case invalidDate
    case missingData
    case noDataChanged
}
```

---

While I believe you should check all of the `sqlite3_xxx` calls for errors, I personally find all of the above a bit ugly. I’d suggest wrapping all the SQLite3 calls to get you out of the weeds. There are lots of them out there. [This a thin wrapper](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/515bbfc751dd97f5d0745dceee32d3b4) simplifies the above code to something like:

```
func insert(_ book: inout Book) throws {
    let query = "INSERT INTO book (bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

    let statement = try database.prepare(query, parameters: [
        book.title, book.author, book.bookDescription, book.createDate, book.image, book.createdBy
    ])
    try statement.step()
    book.id = Int(database.lastRowId())
}

func update(_ book: Book) throws {
    let query = "UPDATE Book SET bookName = ?, bookAuthor = ?, bookDesc = ?, bookDate = ?, bookImg = ?, createdBy = ? WHERE bookId = ?"

    let statement = try database.prepare(query, parameters: [
        book.title, book.author, book.bookDescription, book.createDate, book.image, book.createdBy, book.id
    ])
    try statement.step()
}

func delete(_ book: Book) throws {
    let query = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE bookId = ?"
    let statement = try database.prepare(query, parameters: [book.id])
    try statement.step()
}

func select(bookId: Int) throws -> Book? {
    let query = "SELECT bookId, bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy FROM Book WHERE bookId = ?"
    let statement = try database.prepare(query, parameters: [bookId])
    if try statement.step() == .row {
        return book(for: statement)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func selectAll() throws -> [Book] {
    let query = "SELECT bookId, bookName, bookAuthor, bookDesc, bookDate, bookImg, createdBy FROM Book"
    let statement = try database.prepare(query)

    var books = [Book]()
    while try statement.step() == .row {
        if let book = book(for: statement) {
            books.append(book)
        }
    }
    return books
}

func book(for statement: Statement) -> Book? {
    guard
        let id = Int(from: statement, index: 0),
        let title = String(from: statement, index: 1),
        let author = String(from: statement, index: 2),
        let description = String(from: statement, index: 3),
        let date = Date(from: statement, index: 4),
        let data = Data(from: statement, index: 5),
        let createdBy = String(from: statement, index: 6) else {
            return nil
    }

    return Book(id: id, image: data, title: title, author: author, bookDescription: description, createDate: date, createdBy: createdBy)
}
```

Comment: And everybody working with plain SQLite from Swift should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/1187415 (now also officially a "great answer")

Comment: Thanks Rob! I realized that I missed a question. How do I decode them in the SELECT query? Especially when my database has Date and Blob type. How do I turned SQLite.Date into Swift.Date and SQLite.Blob into Swift.Data?

Comment: If you used `dateFormatter` to convert date to string, like shown above, when retrieving it you'd use `dateFormatter.date(from:)` to convert the string retrieved from `sqlite3_column_text` into a date. And to retrieve the `Data`, use `sqlite3_column_bytes` to get the `count` of the `Data`, use `sqlite3_column_blob` to get the `bytes`, and use `Data(bytes:count)` to build the `Data` object.

Comment: @Rob oh now I get it. So I shouldn't use Date type in database? I think I would use Double type since it's comparable in the query. Just to make things clear, I use timeIntervalSince1970 and insert as Double type, and I use unixepoch to convert Double into Date in the SELECT result. Am I right?

Comment: SQLite has no native date type. Similarly vexing, the types for columns are not enforced. (What we’re they thinking?) See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. By the way, `ISODateFormatter` strings are comparable, too, which is why it’s one of the recommended formats. Just be wary of using custom formatters that (a) aren’t in yyyy-MM-dd format and (b) don’t use a consistent time zone and locale. This is why `ISODateFormatter` is so convenient.

Comment: @Martin R thanks for the link. I have tried some of the wrappers available, but I felt easier doing it in plain SQLite because I could perform operation on datatypes like Blob easily. Maybe wrappers can do that easily and I just don't know how because I'm new to SQLite. I'll put my time studying that after this.

Comment: I second the vote for SQLite wrappers. This approach of making SQLite calls yourself can be fragile (e.g. all to easy to miss a `sqlite3_finalize`; proper checking of binding/retrieving of columns is cumbersome; etc.). I think the above is solid, but it's easy to make mistakes.

Comment: At the risk of beating a dead horse, it's worth noting that SQLite's handling of blobs is a bit inefficient. It's fine for thumbnails, but for larger images there is (or at least was, historically) a material performance hit storing them in the database. For large images we often want to save them in persistent storage ourselves and then just include a reference the local path/file name in the database. If dealing with 10s or 100s of records it might not be material. But if you're storing thousands (or more) of large images, it starts to become a factor.

Comment: Thanks Bob. This helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the wrapper, @Rob , it sort of wraps it all up pretty nicely. One point though; should I instantiate the database instance once and use it throughout my app? or should I create one instance per function access?

Thanks.

Comment: I’ve avoid unnecessary opening and closing of the database. But be careful about multithreaded interaction with the same database, though. I generally just synchronize my interaction with my database instance.

Comment: So I can use one instance throughout then.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing, @Rob please. What optimizations can be done here for bulk inserts? I want to insert multiple records and I am wondering how to reuse the prepared statement.

Comment: Oops.  I have seen the bind(parameters) and the reset method of the Statement class. Thanks

Comment: For bulk operations, you can also further improve performance by using [transactions](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). Do a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, do all the inserts/updates, and then do `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.