# sqlite3 make common function to reduce duplicacy

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am working on the sqlite3 to save and get data.

And i followed two tutorial to 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28642293/4955401)
[link2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/167743/sqlite-swift-tutorial-getting-started)

in both of the links data is saved and get by using binding statements like
to save :-

```
    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "foo", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
    }

    if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure inserting foo: \(errmsg)")
    }
```

and to get:-

```
        let id = sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0)
        print("id = \(id); ", terminator: "")

        if let cString = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) {
            let name = String(cString: cString)
            print("name = \(name)")
        }
```

But as in my projects there are many tables for to save and get get data i don't want to use seperate get and save function for each table.

How should i make common functions so that for each time saving data in any table i just have to send values.

for this approach i get to know about the generics process. But i dont know how to use it.

kindly help me out

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: actually i'm restricted to use only default libraries, So using an external library is not an option.

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/