# How should I access database instance on iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("sampleDB.sqlite")

// open database

var db: OpaquePointer?
if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
    print("error opening database")
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question? What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: I want to access the data inside the .sqlite file and print it, I'm not sure how to do

Comment: You referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift  which has a perfect answer – what exactly is unclear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an SQLite Database in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift)

Comment: Now that you've removed your code, the question is even more "too broad" than it was before. You seem to think Stack Overflow is a free code-writing service. It isn't.

Comment: I just edited the new code bud!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to access a SQLite database by calling actual SQLite C methods is a very confusing and clumsy thing to do. It's much better to use one of the many fine third-party front ends that lets you talk in a natural native Swift way to SQLite.

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: Personally I like FMDB (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). And here is an example of using it: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p821SQLite/ch36p1077SQLite/ViewController.swift

Comment: I just did help you. I gave you good advice and I showed you sample code. I'm not going to write _your_ code for you.