# Select count(col_name) in sqlite (Swift) not working

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

I am using the sqlite wrapper [here](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/515bbfc751dd97f5d0745dceee32d3b4) to access my sqlite database in Swift.

I wrote this code based on the wrapper to count the items on a table.

```
public func numberOfRows() -> Int {

        let cmd = """
        SELECT count(*) from  \(self.tableName)
        """

        do{

            let db = DatabaseUtils.getInstance().getConnection()


            let stmt = try db.prepare( cmd )


            if try stmt.step() == .row {
                return Int(from: stmt,index:  1) ?? -1
            }

            return -1

        }catch {
            Log.out("Error occurred while fetching count data in \(tableName)")
            return -1
        }

    }
```

But it keeps returning -1 as the logic instructs when the count is not found.

Every other thing works so far; create tables, inserts, batched inserts.

Also a `select count(col_name) from table_name where some_col = "?"` also works.

**QUESTION:**

How do I remedy it to work for

```
  SELECT count(*) from  table_name?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column numbers when returning values (e.g. the result of [`sqlite3_column_xxx`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)) are zero-based. You’re attempting to retrieve column `1`, when you meant column `0`.

---

By the way, if you want to detect invalid index, you can remove that `nil` coalescing operator. E.g., so, instead of:

```
if try stmt.step() == .row {
    return Int(from: stmt,index:  1) ?? -1
}
```

You could instead check to see if not only if `step` succeeded, but also that `Int(from:index:)` returned a non-`nil` value:

```
if try stmt.step() == .row {
    if let count = Int(from: stmt, index: 1) {
        return count
    } else {
        // do whatever you want when it fails, e.g.

        fatalError("no value returned; invalid column index?")
    }
}
```

Or perhaps more succinctly:

```
if try stmt.step() == .row, let count = Int(from: stmt, index: 1) {
    return count
} else {
    fatalError("no value returned; invalid column index?")
}
```

That would lead you to recognize that you need the 0-based index:

```
if try stmt.step() == .row, let count = Int(from: stmt, index: 0) {
    return count
} else {
    fatalError("no value returned; invalid column index?")
}
```

Comment: Easy mistake to make especially since parameter binding starts at 1.

Comment: @Shawn, true that!

Comment: @Rob, I just saw your update to the answer. Thanks again. It was very helpful

Comment: @Rob, I really need your help on this question, if possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284543/value-of-type-tags-has-no-member-lastused/65288927?noredirect=1#comment115423782_65288927